# Publicar aplicación de manera correcta hecha en Visual estudio Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, reportviewer

Buenas tardes mi problema es el siguiente. al querer publicar mi aplicación en en visual estudio o hacer una compilación de solución Realese. No me exporta mis Reportes RDLC de Report Viewer. Entonces al hacer la Publicacion e intalar el programa en otra maquina me da error al genera reportes. por que no encuentra los archivos de reportes. Como puedo generar estos archivos que visual no me exporta al ejecutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Establece las propiedades de reporte(click derecho> propiedades) **Build accion: content** y **Copy to output : Copy if never**  asi:

[image: propiedades visual studio]

Comment: Yo sugeriría poner Copy Always y así te evitas problemas, porque si le dejas Copy if newer si alguien va y los borra de la carpeta no se van a volver a copiar, de igual manera si los modificas no se va a copiar la ultima version con las modificaciones